# How to add a panel/box/widget/are/screen to the right side of edit post/page confusion

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, admin-ui

I have been reading through the WP plugin docs to try and figure out how to display information on the right side of a post or page when an admin is creating or editing a post or page. I don't seem to be able to find this anywhere or I got something wrong, right now I am just confused.

I read about Dashboard widgets and tried it, but they only displayed the widget on the dashboard not when editing a post/page.

Then I thought it could be done with metabox, but that seems to only add a custom field to the settings bar. I need to use html/php/jquery so I guess that will not work either.

I just want a panel to the right that is visible when a user/admin edits a page/post. In the panel I need to use html/php/jquery.  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using classic editor, then [add_meta_box()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) will do the trick. Just make sure you set the context as "side".

With Gutenberg I think you'll need a [Panel component](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/panel/). I'm not too familiar with Gutenberg so I can't comment more on this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I looked some more at meta boxes but I came across this pretty soon "Note there are no submit buttons in meta boxes. The meta box HTML is included inside the edit screen’s form tags, all the post data including meta box values are transfered via POST when the user clicks on the Publish or Update buttons." So this will not work for me unless there is a way around it?

Comment: Looks like I can get around this by using ajax, accepted.

Comment: @AndreasToresäter Yes, if you need a button on a metabox and have it do something, you can attach a custom js/jquery click action, which executes some ajax function, to a button element in the metabox. I've done something similar on few occasions. And any input fields inside the metabox don't matter for the default Publish/Update functionality as long as you don't handle the fields with a custom `save_post` action.